# Ubuntu login error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

On my ubuntu machine when I am trying to login I am receiving an error :

```
mount : mounting /dev on /root/sys failed : No such file or directory
mount : mounting /proc on /root/proc failed : No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found.Try passing init= bootarg

(initramfs)
```

Even after entering into the rescue mode I am not able to use the command `sudo` and `fsck`.
When I use try to use them it gives an error:

```
/bin/sh: fsck or sudo : not found
```

Comment: At what stage do things go wrong? Reading the post it seems as if it goes wrong when you try to log in, but the errors seem more consistent with problems long before that. (e.g. with no root filesystem found).

Answer (score 0):

it looks like something has corrupted your filesystem. Are you able to boot without any error messages or that is also gone ? If boot process has problems as well, try booting into a live CD or USB image and once you get to the shell execute:

```
fsck -f /dev/sda1
```

assuming your disk drive was at sda1 location. If not, change it accordingly. Then answer YES to "do you want to fix it" questions as they come. It might help if the amount of corruption is not too extensive.